# How 10 tables with different number names can be created in a loop using Transact SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, loops, create-table

Can you give me any advice?
I have to create 10 tables which names are "Image" with different number e.g. "Image1", "Image2" and so on. I've made a Transact-SQL code like this:

```
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @v_table_n CHAR
SET @i=1
SET @v_table_n='Image'
WHILE (@i<=1000)
BEGIN
SET @v_table_n+='i';
EXECUTE IMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SQL_DB_Filestream.dbo.Image1'+@v_table_n+
(
[ID_RowFeatVec] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Junction1,
[CF1] FLOAT,
[CF2] FLOAT,
[CF3] FLOAT    
)
END
GO
```

Unfortunately, there is a mistake message:"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near '+'."

Do you have any idea of what I have to do to receive 10 tables with different names?

Comment: As a side comment:  creating multiple tables with the same format is very rarely advisable.  In almost all cases, one table will perform better and simplify queries and database maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
SET @v_table_n = @v_table_n + 'i';
```

T-SQL does not use the += syntax for increment.

Secondly, as Rowland has also pointed out, you are not using dynamic SQL correctly. You need to create your query string first, and then execute it, something like this:

```
DECLARE @createstmt NVARCHAR(8000)
SET @createstmt = 'CREATE TABLE SQL_DB_Filestream.dbo.Image1' + @v_table_ + '([ID_RowFeatVec] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Junction1,[CF1] FLOAT,[CF2] FLOAT,[CF3] FLOAT)'
EXECUTE @createstmt
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting should give it away - your table definition isn't there as a string, so you've a trailing concatenation with nothing to concatenate.

Additionally, you're making up your own syntax, as `+=` isn't support in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @v_table_n CHAR
SET @i=1
SET @v_table_n='Image'
WHILE (@i<=1000)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(100)

    SET @STR = 'CREATE TABLE SQL_DB_Filestream.dbo.Image1' + @v_table_n + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' (
        [ID_RowFeatVec] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Junction1,
        [CF1] FLOAT,
        [CF2] FLOAT,
        [CF3] FLOAT    
    )'

    EXECUTE @STR

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
GO
```

Comment: An error message appears: "Could not find stored procedure 'IMMEDIATE'."

Comment: I cannot see why it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion on how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Just use EXECUTE, I think EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is an Oracle thing.

Answer (score -1):

set the value as start and than increment it in while loop

```
    SET @v_table_n ='i';
   WHILE (@i<=1000)
  BEGIN

 EXECUTE IMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SQL_DB_Filestream.dbo.Image1'+@v_table_n+
 (
 [ID_RowFeatVec] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Junction1,
 [CF1] FLOAT,
 [CF2] FLOAT,
 [CF3] FLOAT    
 )
  SET @v_table_n ='i' + 1;
 END
 GO
```